# Is there any alternative for UIGetScreenImage in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I tried the below code to get the screenshot of full iPhone screen using objective-c.It worked perfectly in iPhone using objective-c.But I  am not getting the screenshot of full screen in swift.Can anyone please provide me some information regarding this?

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
CGImageRelease(screen);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't get UIGetScreenImage in swift.Is there any other method for taking screenshot of full screen in swift.I tried the below code in swift. var keyWindow : UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
        var rect : CGRect = keyWindow.bounds

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, true, 0.0)
        var context : CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        keyWindow.layer .renderInContext(context)
        var capturedScreen : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
        let nsUserDomainMask = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
        if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true) {

Comment: if paths.count > 0 {
                if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
                    let writePath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image.png")
                    UIImagePNGRepresentation(capturedScreen).writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true)
                }
            }
        }(Using the above code I am getting only the view screen but not getting the alertview(Which is placed on above window level)

Comment: update your code into question.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension UIView {
    var snapshot: UIImage {
        get {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
            self.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image
        }
    }
}
```